# Why does Length[Names["System`*"]] give different values on Windows and Linux?

Tags: system, installation

I was just curious about this.

```
Length[Names["System`*"]]
```

Gives slightly different value on Linux and Windows 10.  I was wondering why that is as I have expected the same exact value on both systems. The build date is different, but that is not as important as the system names being different.

[image]

What does the above command give on the mac?  7405 or 7402 or something else? Does this difference mean that there are some system names that exist on Linux only and not on windows?

Comment: You could export one of the lists as a text file and import it on the other computer and take the compliment to see what the extra ones are. (On 13.1.0 for Windows, I only have 7400.)

Comment: On `"12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"` I get `6979`.

Comment: Since you asked explicitly for a mac: `"12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)"` I get `6585`